# How does looping over a Mysql table actually work?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I know what `foreach` stands for and the use of it. But I think I am misusing it. I have a cart table in the database that is dynamically being filled when user add products on the website through a html form. 
[There are actually two products in the cart table/phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa9FT.png)

I'm having a hard time displaying the products on the user side.

With this first code I'm able to display all the rows but not the product informations.

```
   <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

        $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
        $items =  json_decode($result['items'],true);
        $i = 1;
        $sub_total = 0;
        $item_count = 0;

    ?>
      <h2 class="text-center">My Cart</h2>

      <?php if($cartQ->num_rows== 0): ?>
      Your cart is empty.

      <?php elseif($cartQ->num_rows > 0): ?>
              <?php

        foreach ($cartQ as $item) {
                      $product_id = $item['id'];
                      $productQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id ='{$product_id}' ");
                      $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQuery);
                 ?>

                    <tr class="p">
        <td class="image"><img src="<?=$product['image_1'];?>" /></td>
        <td class="name"><?=$product['prod_name'];?></td>
        <td class="price"><?=money($product['price']);?></td>
        <td class="quantity"> <?=$item['quantity'];?></td>
        <td class="pricesubtotal"><?=money($item['quantity'] * $product['price'] );?></td>
        <td class=""><div><button name='removeitem' onclick="update_cart('removeitem','<?=$product_id['id'];?>');">&times</button></div></td>
      </tr>    
<?php endif;?>
```

With this second code I'm able to display product information but only one row displays at a the time (usually last product added).

```
   <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

         $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id ='{$cart_id}' ");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
        $items =  json_decode($result['items'],true);
        $i = 1;
        $sub_total = 0;
        $item_count = 0;

    ?>
      <h2 class="text-center">My Cart</h2>

      <?php if($cartQ->num_rows== 0): ?>
      Your cart is empty.

      <?php elseif($cartQ->num_rows > 0): ?>
              <?php

        foreach ($items as $item) {
                      $product_id = $item['id'];
                      $productQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id ='{$product_id}' ");
                      $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQuery);
                 ?>

                    <tr class="p">
        <td class="image"><img src="<?=$product['image_1'];?>" /></td>
        <td class="name"><?=$product['prod_name'];?></td>
        <td class="price"><?=money($product['price']);?></td>
        <td class="quantity"> <?=$item['quantity'];?></td>
        <td class="pricesubtotal"><?=money($item['quantity'] * $product['price'] );?></td>
        <td class=""><div><button name='removeitem' onclick="update_cart('removeitem','<?=$product_id['id'];?>');">&times</button></div></td>
      </tr>    
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Please check your `query`. When you say "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id ='{$cart_id}'", it only select **ONE** result. Consider the "SELECT * FROM cart" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a result, PHP/mySql maintain a cursor (this can be in MySQL or PHP depending on your settings), but they work the same for the end-user.

I's easier if we annotate your code:

```
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id ='{$cart_id}' ");
// CartQ containes a "Query Result" (which may be false if it failed - check for false !)
// At this stage, the "Query Result" is sitting on the first item

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
// $result actually contains the first row of data, **and has moved the "Query Result" cursor to the second row** 

if($cartQ->num_rows== 0)
// This does not move the cursor.
```

So what you need to do, if you want more than one result, is loop around the results.

```
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id ='{$cart_id}' ");
if ($cartQ == false) {
    // SQL Error - debug me
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ)) {   
        // Do something with the $row
        // Will keep looping until all rows consumed
        // Won't enter if there are no rows.
    }
    // Cursor now sits on (last+1) row (i.e. off the end).
}
```

---

Side note: you can "join tables" and do all this in one query by not storing in JSON. Will make it easier to say "get all product details for all products in cart" in one go. You can only do JSON in mySQL 5.7+, but it's more efficient not to do it in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it out in few seconds. Before everything I wanted to precise I did join the tables together. But I'm still a noob so I might have made some mistakes along the way.

Comment: I'm not being critical (with the join comments) just trying to nudge you in the right direction. Get what you have working first (one step at a time) but then consider removing the JSON in favour of JOINS an an intermediary "cart_items" table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to loop through the whole record set. NO, you can just perform a `JOIN` among the tables and get the desired record like

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM product p
JOIN cart c ON p.id = c.id;
```